# Obtener hostname desde MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un formulario que cada vez que se inserta un registro o se modifica agrega el hostname en un campo del SQL, el detalle que cuando pase el sistema al servidor donde estaría alojado me pone el hostname del servidor. ¿Podría de alguna manera obtener el hostname de la máquina que está usando el sistema y este guardar? Actualmente así obtengo el hostname desde el código en c#

```
 string computer_name = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Quieres el hostname del cliente?

Comment: si, necesito el hosname de la maquina en la que se hicieron las modificaciones

Comment: Recuerda que en tu IIS debes de tener activado el Windows Authentification, para poder obtener el usuario dentro del domino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar lo siguiente
[HttpRequest.UserHostAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) y [HttpRequest.UserHostName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostname(v=vs.110).aspx) para obtener tanto la IP cliente como el nombre de la máquina cliente. 
Un código de ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mvc.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : ClientController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
            string hostName = Request.UserHostName;

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para que la respuesta no dependa sólo de un link (que MS puede cambiar y hacer inválido), podrías amplar la respuesta con algún ejemplo breve que le indique al OP cómo usar el recurso que le sugieres? :)

Comment: Editado. Un saludo

Comment: string hostName = Request.UserHostName;
solo me regresa = ::1

Comment: Eso es `localhost` en IPv6

Comment: aun no pongo el cambio en el servidor productivo para validar si obtiene bien el hostname, una duda.. Esto también se podría hacer desde un SP de SQL? o al hacerlo desde SQL me arrojaría el hostname del servidor?